# Why does my derived class constructor not work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino

I have been working to create an Arduino library to control a touchscreen. My library builds off of pre-existing libraries written to interface with the display & touch controllers.

Here is the constructor that I have been working on:

Display.cpp

```
Display::Display(int displayCSPin, int displayDCPin, int touchCSPin,
                 int newBacklightPin, int newRotation, int newBrightness)
    : Adafruit_HX8357(displayCSPin, displayDCPin, -1), 
      Adafruit_STMPE610(touchCSPin)
{
//Initialize display
}
```

Display.h

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H_
#define DISPLAY_H_

#include "arduino.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_HX8357.h"
#include "Adafruit_STMPE610.h"

class Display : public Adafruit_HX8357, Adafruit_STMPE610 {
public:
    Display(int displayCSPin, int displayDCPin, int touchCSPin,
            int newBacklightPin, int newRotation, int newBrightness);
};
```

Whenever I try to compile, the compiler ignores the variables in the base class constructors, and tries to call a default constructor with no variables:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_HX8357::Adafruit_HX8357()'
```

I have tried my best to solve this problem, but have not had any success.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the raw code:

Display.cpp

```
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display(int displayCSPin, int displayDCPin, int touchCSPin, int newBacklightPin, int newRotation, int newBrightness) : Adafruit_HX8357(displayCSPin, displayDCPin, -1), Adafruit_STMPE610(touchCSPin)
{

    // tft = Adafruit_HX8357(displayCSPin, displayDCPin, -1);
    //ts = Adafruit_STMPE610(touchCSPin);
    tft.begin(HX8357D);
    ts.begin();
    tft.setRotation(newRotation);
    backlightPin = newBacklightPin;
    pinMode(backlightPin, OUTPUT);

    rotation = newRotation;
    backgroundColor = HX8357_BLACK;
    brightness = newBrightness;

}
```

Display.h

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H_
#define DISPLAY_H_

#include "arduino.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_HX8357.h"
#include "Adafruit_STMPE610.h"

class Display : public Adafruit_HX8357, public Adafruit_STMPE610 {
public:
    Display(int displayCSPin, int displayDCPin, int touchCSPin, int newBacklightPin, int newRotation, int newBrightness);

    void wake();
    void sleep();
    bool isAwake();
    void setBackGroundColor(int newColor);
    int getBackgroundColor();
    void setBrightness(int newBrightness);
    int getBrightness();
    void setRotation(int newRotation);
    int getRotation();
    bool isTouched();
    Adafruit_HX8357 tft;
    Adafruit_STMPE610 ts;
    int backgroundColor;

private:
    int brightness;
    int rotation;
    int backlightPin;
    bool awake;
    bool touched;
    TS_Point p;

};
```

Comment: Can you even call multiple superclass constructors in one constructor?

Comment: @RonThompson all base classes must have a constructor called. (If they're not mentioned in the init list then they get called with no arguments)

Comment: @RonThompson: yes, you can.

Comment: You are using `private` inheritance with `Adafruit_STMPE610`, was that intentional?  (you need `public` before it to use public)

Comment: Is this actually your real code? Have you confirmed that the error message comes from the lines of code you posted here? (the message should include numbers saying which line it came from). As posted it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MattMcNabb This is the real code with the fat trimmed (starting the i2c interface, initializing some variables). The error is definitely coming from the line of code where the constructor is. I can post the raw code if that would be helpful. `Adafruit_STMPE610` is meant to be public, that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @PlanetaryN: please do post the 'raw code' - something as simple as a stray semicolon could explain this... could easily have been missed out when you prepared the above.

Comment: @TonyD: I appended the raw code to the end of the original question. Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: @PlanetaryN: very strange.  If you put `Adafruit_HX8357 a(1,2,3);` on a line above the `Display::Display` constructor definition in `display.cpp`, does that compile?  Checking will also ensure you're looking at the same version of the files the build system is using.  You could also try compiling with `-E` to check preprocessor output... make sure you can see the expected `Adafruit_HX8357` 3-argument constructor and there're no bogus macro replacements happening in the `Display` constructor line.

Comment: @TonyD: I tried placing the  `Adafruit_HX8357 a(1,2,3);` line above the `Display::Display` constructor definition, but it unfortunately made no difference. Could you clarify what you mean by compiling with `-E`? I'm not sure what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @PlanetaryN: most compilers accept `-E` as a command line argument to stop after the preprocessing stage (for Visual C++, it's `cl /E`) - that allows you to see exactly what's happened after all `#if` / `#else` / `#endif` and macro substitutions have been processed.  You can then check that the base class constructor's actually making it into your translation unit, and the construction code hasn't been corrupted by some unintended macro substitution.  It's a long shot, but when something clearly should work and doesn't long shots are all there is....

Comment: @PlanetaryN *"it unfortunately made no difference"* - that diagnostic indicates whether the `Adafruit_HX8357` three-`int`-argument constructor is available for use as expected.  Did you get an error on that line, or did it compile successfully?  If you got an error, check you haven't done something funny like `#include <Adafruit_HX8357.h>` from within a namespace in `arduino.h`.  Again, searching for the constructor in the `-E` output may help....

Comment: @TonyD: When I have `Adafruit_HX8357 a(1,2,3);` above the constructor, the program does not compile, and the error is still coming from the constructor (`Display::Display...` line). I will work on getting the -E output now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the actual constructors available for `Adafruit_HX8357` and `Adafruit_STMPE610`:

```
Adafruit_HX8357(int8_t _CS, int8_t _DC, int8_t _MOSI, int8_t _SCLK, 
                int8_t _RST, int8_t _MISO); 
Adafruit_HX8357(int8_t _CS, int8_t _DC, int8_t _RST = -1);
```

```
Adafruit_STMPE610(uint8_t cspin, uint8_t mosipin, uint8_t misopin, uint8_t clkpin); 
Adafruit_STMPE610(uint8_t cs); 
Adafruit_STMPE610(void);
```

Your `Display` constructor is trying to call the second constructor of each class.  However, `Display` is passing `int` values where `int8_t` and `uint8_t` values are expected.  It sounds like maybe your compiler is not performing implicit conversions from `int` to `(u)int8_t`, so try using explicit conversions to force it:

```
Display::Display(int displayCSPin, int displayDCPin, int touchCSPin, int newBacklightPin, int newRotation, int newBrightness)
    : Adafruit_HX8357((int8_t)displayCSPin, (int8_t)displayDCPin, -1),
      Adafruit_STMPE610((uint8_t)touchCSPin)
{
    //Initialize display
}
```

Otherwise, change you `Display` constructor parameters to use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` instead of `int`:

```
Display::Display(int8_t displayCSPin, int8_t displayDCPin, uint8_t touchCSPin, int newBacklightPin, int newRotation, int newBrightness)
    : Adafruit_HX8357(displayCSPin, displayDCPin, -1),
      Adafruit_STMPE610(touchCSPin)
{
    //Initialize display
}
```

Comment: There is implicit conversion between integral types in C++ so it seems likely that something else is going on

Comment: I just tried both casting the variables & declaring them as `int8_t`, and unfortunately it had no effect.